# "Обварен(н)ых стальными листами и обмотанных колючей проволокой" — одна или две Н?

Tags: нн

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пишется ли двойная **нн** в слове "обварен(н)ых". Перечитала все правила про отглагольные прилагательные, но наспех, без постоянной практики разобраться не могу. Какая-то оставшаяся от школьных знаний чуйка хочет написать "обвареных" с одной **н** (может, потому что их не обварили в кипятке, а обварили металлом), а "обмотанных" уже с двумя **нн**, но объяснить это себе не могу. Как правильно?

Comment: Что за чуйка хочет так написать? ^_^

Comment: Не знаю. Видимо, правила в голове спутались и какое-то упорно лезет вперёд невпопад. Сама не знаю. Вот если бы что-то было обварено кипятком - не задумываясь, поставила бы две нн, а вот это "обваренные металлом" прям как-то встали поперёк в голове и сижу думаю над ними. Но ответ ваш принимаю, спасибо.

Comment: Не за что) Я не понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под "чуйкой"? Это же вид одежды, ныне не существующей.

Comment: ЧУЙКА II
1. прост. интуиция, шестое чувство https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Интересно! От "чуять", значит. :)

Comment: Да, так и есть. Ну вот и я вас чему-то научила)

Comment: Да, спасибо и вам!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приставка (об-) есть, значит, это уже причастие с двумя Н. Тем более ещё есть зависимые слова ("стальными листами").